# CSS grid span row to all rows

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[image]

I want to make like this layout. but I can not make the `.head` element full rows. I also try with `grid-row: 1 / 6`, but it is not responsive when width change it not properly span rows. `grid-column: 1 / -1` working fine `grid-row: 1 / -1` this not working.

```css
.mgrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(91px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 4px;
}

.head {
  background: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}

.item {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="mgrid">
  <div class="head">My Text</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: not able to find the duplicate but you either use grid-row: 1/99 (and replace the gap with margin) or consider position: absolute

Comment: this will not supper responsive !!!!

Comment: those are the only ways

Comment: If you're okay to nest one grid within another, then that would seem the easiest solution: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ogc78fte/), but I will admit that it's non-ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using `position: absolute`

```css
.mgrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(91px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 4px;
  padding-left: 95px; /* 91px + gap */
  position: relative;
}

.head {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 91px; /* same as the template */
  background: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.item {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="mgrid">
  <div class="head">My Text</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ```<div class="flex"><div class="head">My Text</div><div class="mgrid"><div class="item">item</div>... ...</div></div>```

Comment: @Abhijit if you are able to adjust the HTML then it's another story, we have a ton of different ways to do this